# Using XPath to find a dynamic table value

Tags: html, xpath

In this table with dynamically changing prices, I wish to always select the link belonging to the first price over $400,00 in XPath 1.0. The correct solution might not always be in the second row, so `tr[2]/td[1]` will not always be the correct result.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><a href="/somesite/page.htm?id=1">1</a></td>
      <td>-$200,00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><a href="/somesite/page.htm?id=2">2</a></td>
      <td>$500,00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><a href="/somesite/page.htm?id=3">3</a></td>
      <td>$100,00</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My (non-working) XPath that comes closest so far is:

```
//tr/td[2][starts-with(.,'$')]/(number(substring-after(.,'$')))>400.00/preceding-sibling::td
```

- It selects the prices by using `td[2]`
- It only selects the prices that have positive values (I don't need the negative values anyway)
- It removes the `$` signs from the remaining prices

**Here is the problem:**

- I'm trying to use number to convert the strings into numbers so I can compare them to 400 (which is not working)
- After that I try to select the corresponding link after the right price has been found.

Any help would be really appreciated (I'm just a simple tester getting dragged into the magical world of test automation) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to always select the link belonging to the first price over $400,00 in XPath 1.0.

That would be

```
//td[number(translate(normalize-space(), ',$', '.')) > 400]/..//a
```

Note that I translate `,` to `.` and `$` to nothing<sup>**</sup>, so if your numbers are formatted any further (digit grouping, for example) this might not be 100% correct yet. Know your data, make the appropriate changes.

For the fun of it (and to demonstrate XPath's flexibility), here's a different path with the same result:

```
//a[../..//td[number(translate(normalize-space(), ',$', '.')) > 400]]
```

---

<sup>**</sup> `translate()` replaces one list of characters with another:

- `translate('abc', 'ac', 'AC')` returns `'AbC'`
- `translate('abc', 'ac', 'A')` returns `'Ab'`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've tried both variants and they work great.